# PostgrSQL custom Docker Container

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker, ssl

I am trying to write a docker entrypoint script, that’s able to start postgreSQL and creating a new named database.

**I feel like there is a much better way, than mine. I am  happy for every input.**

Issues:

- a few times I have to restart the container befor it creates the databas and does not crash. Some times I don't know why it workes. I can't recreate it right now.
- Freequently I get messages like `[unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet` but there shouldn't be any.

Reason for custom docker image: I need PostgreSQL to use ssl for every connection. The official image is sadly not able to allow ssl with real certificates.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:10.9

RUN apt update && apt install -y \
    postgresql postgresql-contrib \
    openssl \
    net-tools netcat \
    vim

RUN mkdir database_stuff

COPY --chown=postgres:postgres ./entrypoint.sh /database_stuff/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 777 /database_stuff/entrypoint.sh

COPY --chown=postgres:postgres ./certificates/cert.pem /database_stuff/cert.pem
RUN chmod 600 /database_stuff/cert.pem
COPY --chown=postgres:postgres ./certificates/key.pem /database_stuff/key.pem
RUN chmod 600 /database_stuff/key.pem

COPY --chown=postgres:postgres ./configuration/postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf
COPY --chown=postgres:postgres ./configuration/pg_hba.conf /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf

VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]

USER postgres

CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/11/main/", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/database_stuff/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "START entrypoint.sh"

echo "start postgrSQL"
/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/ -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf &

until nc -z db 5432; do
  sleep 0.1
done

echo "create Database"
psql -U postgres -c 'create database part_screening;'
psql -U postgres -c "create user alstom with encrypted password 'Laser765_f';"

echo "END entrypoint.sh .... Stay open"
tail -f /dev/null
```

just a log with the `unknown@unknown` issue

```
START entrypoint.sh

start postgrSQL

create Database

CREATE DATABASE

CREATE ROLE

END entrypoint.sh .... Stay open


2021-08-02 17:08:52.280 UTC [7] LOG: listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432

2021-08-02 17:08:52.280 UTC [7] LOG: listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432

2021-08-02 17:08:52.284 UTC [7] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

2021-08-02 17:08:52.300 UTC [10] LOG: database system was shut down at 2021-08-02 17:06:42 UTC

2021-08-02 17:08:52.305 UTC [7] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections

2021-08-02 17:08:52.330 UTC [18] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG: incomplete startup packet

2021-08-02 17:08:53.145 UTC [38] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG: incomplete startup packet
```

Comment: That `incomplete startup packet` message gets generated when `nc` connects to the database, and then disconnects before sending any data.  It's not necessarily wrong.

Comment: (Remember that anyone who has a copy of this image can `docker run --rm your-image cat /database_stuff/key.pem` to get the secret key out; you should not include credentials like this in a Docker image.)

Comment: @DavidMaze that is an interesting comment - thank you - but I can’t think of an alternative? The key has to be somewhere?

Comment: Using `docker run -v` to bind-mount it from the host would be a typical approach.

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand what you mean. In this situation everyone who has a copy, is the same person who has access to the server.